# How to make scrolling work only on one <div>?

Tags: css, overflow, screen-orientation

edit: Solved, answer in comments

I'm trying to get the right side of this thing to scroll while the left side stays put, but only in landscape. I had some success using `position: fixed`, but it would require a page refresh whenever switching between landscape/portrait because the map wouldn't switch styles. Now I'm trying (and failing) to use `overflow`. Any idea how to do this properly?

https://codepen.io/dvtan/pen/mYrzqo

Copy of codepen:

```
<style>
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    body > div {
        flex: 1;
    }
    #map {
        height: 100vh;
    }
    #right {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
    #map {
        height: 50vh;
    }
}
</style>

<body>
  <div id="left">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>scrollable<br>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
    let leafletMap = L.map('map').fitBounds([
        [45, -63],
        [40, -124]
    ]);
    let normalLayer = L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        'attribution': '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });
    leafletMap.addLayer(normalLayer);
</script>
```

Comment: Giving your `#right` div a fixed `height` can allow its content inside to be scrolled while keeping div in one position.

Comment: @ShivCKushawah It worked, thank you! All it needed was `#right {height: 100vh;}`. If you want to create an answer, I'll accept it, or I can delete this question since it was so simple

Comment: that's ok.  Main purpose was to solve your problem. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need fixed height in order for overflow property to work. SO by making you height element 100% should do the work.

```
#yourElement {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The difference between overflow scroll and auto is that when it's scroll the scrollbar is always visible even if there is no content to scroll.